# Problem with DD & Startup disk creator

Tags: usb, chromium, dd, startup-disk-creator

I want to create a bootable USB drive for Chromium OS. I downloaded this image ([*direct link*](http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/daily/Camd64OS-20150402010101.img.7z)) and I want to put it on my `4 Gb` USB. The `IMG` file is `2.6 Gb` and my USB is `4 Gb`, so there is space for the image.

When I run `DD` (`dd if=ChromeOS.img of=/media/felixinx/0392-8145 bs=4M`), I get `dd: impossible d'ouvrir «/media/felixinx/0392-8145»: est un dossier` as error (*/media/felixinx/0392-8145 is a folder*).

With [Startup Disk Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), I get an error : `Impossible d'écrire l'image disque (/home/felixinx/Téléchargements/ChromeOS.img) sur le périphérique (/dev/sdb1).` (*Impossible to write image on the disk*).

With `sudo usb-creator-gtk`, I get the same error, with a `Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.` message on command line. (Yay! First error message in english!).

I don't know why is don't work.

Thanks

Comment: I just want to say that I was having the same error message, but in my case adding `sudo` to `usb-creator-gtk` solved my issue. So for future searchers: it's worth a shot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device is mounted. Your OS is using it, so it will not work correctly.

Also, you need to dd to a "/dev/xda" device, and not a mount point.

You will need to run:

```
sudo umount /media/felixinx/0392-8145
```

Then, run

```
blkid
```

to find out the device, maybe it will be `/dev/sdb`, so run:

```
sudo dd if=ChromeOS.img of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

Should work, if not, post the result. If you cannot unmount, just reboot, and don't open the file manager.

Comment: At the end, I have `dd: erreur d'écriture de «/dev/sdb»: Aucun espace disponible sur le périphérique`
`490+0 enregistrements lus`
`489+0 enregistrements écrits`
`2054717440 octets (2,1 GB) copiés, 140,249 s, 14,7 MB/s`
It's said there is no place... but I the file is `2.1 Gb` and my USB is `4 Gb`. On the file manager, my USB is empty.

Comment: I think you should try another thumbdrive... Firstly run `mount`and make sure, there is nothing mounted on the thumbdrive...

Comment: Don't run `of=/dev/sdb1`, you must run `of=/dev/sdb`. `sdb1` would be a partition, `sdb` is the device. You could also run `dd if=/dev/sdb of=image.img bs=4M`, and post the result. If it stops after 2GiB, there must be something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Xfce Desktop Environment.
I switched to gnome, run the same app and it asked for sudo access. So in my case it was matter of sudo to write an image to thumb drive.